# SOAP XML Read in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I couldn't read `soap xml file` . I need to take `partition` element in array

This is my service response:

```
<?php $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetNetworkTopologyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetNetworkTopologyResult>
                <Action Type="NetworkTopology" Result="OK">
                    <topology MinVSATID="1280" MaxVSATID="376">
                        <partition UID="1" NAME="System">
                            <lvg UID="3605" NAME="BS_TEST"/>
                            <lvg UID="4452" NAME="Colocated VATS BH"/>
                            <lvg UID="4530" NAME="SkyMesh_V40"/>
                            <lvg UID="4845" NAME="Bordernet_V45"/>
                            <lvg UID="4846" NAME="HarbourIT_V42"/>
                            <lvg UID="4847" NAME="AN_V43"/>
                            <lvg UID="4848" NAME="ANT_V44"/>
                            <lvg UID="4850" NAME="Clrnet_V41"/>
                            <lvg UID="4851" NAME="Oion_V46"/>
                            <lvg UID="14072" NAME="NBNCo_V47"/>
                            <lvg UID="15811" NAME="iit_V50"/>
                            <lvg UID="15812" NAME="IPStar_V49"/>
                            <lvg UID="17784" NAME="COLOCATED"/>
                            <lvg UID="20655" NAME="Bluemaxx_V52"/>
                            <lvg UID="21333" NAME="SkyMesh_V55"/>
                            <lvg UID="22782" NAME="Indigo_V54"/>
                            <lvg UID="24836" NAME="NBDemo_V51"/>
                            <wg UID="457" NAME="OB_1" LAPUADDRESS="256" HSP="65" HSPIP="2.17.1.1"/>
                            <wg UID="25397" NAME="OB_1_VoIP" LAPUADDRESS="260"/>
                            <wg UID="27795" NAME="OB_1_WE" LAPUADDRESS="258"/>
                            <sg UID="8881" NAME="OB_60_52_00_14" LAPUADDRESS="515" VERSION="6.5.00.14">
                                <dataTPL UID="25197" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="25195" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="25193" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="25191" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="17031" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="14168" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="8876" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="8874" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                            </sg>
                            <sg UID="25396" NAME="OB_60_52_00_22" LAPUADDRESS="517" VERSION="6.2.00.22">
                                <dataTPL UID="27598" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27596" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_61-70"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27594" NAME="DPS_11_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27592" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27590" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_37-52"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27588" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_53-60"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27586" NAME="DPS_11_6_52_00_22_VLAN_53-60"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="25395" NAME="DPS_11_6_52_00_22_VLAN_37-52"/>
                            </sg>
                            <sg UID="27796" NAME="OB_NS1_60_52_01_18" LAPUADDRESS="518" VERSION="6.1.01.18">
                                <dataTPL UID="27814" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27812" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27810" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27808" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27806" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27804" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27802" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                                <dataTPL UID="27798" NAME="DPS_12_6_52_00_22_VLAN_71-80"/>
                            </sg>
                        </partition>
                    </topology>
                </Action>
            </GetNetworkTopologyResult>
        </GetNetworkTopologyResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'




print_r($xml);  // Return empty . no output
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('GetNetworkTopologyResponse', 'http://tempuri.org/');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//GetNetworkTopologyResponse:GetNetworkTopologyResult') as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}
```

Please tell me , what is an issue in my code. I am new to php.

any helps please.

Thanks

Comment: your fatal error simply means that `$xml` is not an object. use `print_r` to print the contents of `$xml`. Moreover, you have used `$soap_response` but didnt defined it anywhere before using it.

Comment: Return empty. I did `print_r($xml)` . It return empty. Pls tell me how to read.

Comment: do you want to read a file or response is in string?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question. When `print_r($xml)` , it did not return anythink.pls guide me

Comment: check my updated answer. Hope it helps...

Comment: place semicolon at the end of the string. `</soap:Envelope>` becomes `</soap:Envelope>;`

Comment: @Piraba: My answer work properly but you have to save xml file differently and xml code separtly. As it was earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("text.xml");
print_r($xml);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('GetNetworkTopologyResponse', 'http://tempuri.org/');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//GetNetworkTopologyResponse:GetNetworkTopologyResult') as $item)
{
print_r($item);
}
?>
```

This will print the array of element and now you can make partitions of array.

" *MAKE SURE THAT YOUR XML SOAP FILE (test.xml) STARTED WITH `<?XML.....>` Without any blank space at the begining of the file,otherwise an error occurs:* `XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`"

Comment: Thanks a lot....one more question , inside foop  how to take `lvg tag name element` pls any idea  I did like this `foreach ($xml->xpath('//GetNetworkTopologyResponse:lvg') as $item)
{
   
     echo (string)$item->name;
}`

Comment: @Piraba: 
`$json_string = json_encode($item);
   
$result= json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
$r=$result['0']['@attributes']['NAME'];
echo $r;`

Add this code to the previous one. You get the Value of first lvg tag name.for others 'change 0 with 1,2,3...and so on'

Answer (score 1):

There is one warning and one fatal error.

The reason you have warning is:
You have used `$soap_response` but neither defined it nor assigned any value to it.

Moreover, fatal error has occured because:
`$xml` is not an object as [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) needs first string parameter.

And you are trying to call a member function on a variable which is not an object.

**Try this**

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xmlObj->registerXPathNamespace('envoy', 'http://apilistener.envoyservices.com');
foreach ($xmlObj->xpath('//envoy:payment') as $item){
    print_r($item);
}
```